# Perl + how to add lines before word in file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl

I write the following code in my bash script ( runs on redhat 7.2 version )

in order to add the content of $info variable before the word – **ERROR:** in file

```
export info="The Postfix error(8) delivery agent processes delivery requests from the queue manager. Each request specifies a queue file, a sender address, the reason for non-delivery (specified as the next-hop destination), and recipient"
perl -i -plne 'print "$ENV{info}" if(/ERROR:/);' file
```

after we run the code the output of file that we can see is too long and its better to separate the line to 3 lines

```
more file

The Postfix error(8) delivery agent processes delivery requests from the queue manager. Each request specifies a queue file, a sender address, the reason for non-delivery (specified as the next-hop destination), and recipient
ERROR:
```

So I add “\n” in the info line as the following:
and we run the code again

```
export info="The Postfix error(8) delivery agent processes delivery requests from the queue manager. \nEach request specifies a queue file, a sender address, \nthe reason for non-delivery (specified as the next-hop destination), and recipient"
perl -i -plne 'print "$ENV{info}" if(/ERROR:/);' file
```

but the file still not include the new lines ( actually the "\n" are in line )

```
The Postfix error(8) delivery agent processes delivery requests from the queue manager. \nEach request specifies a queue file, a sender address, \nthe reason for non-delivery (specified as the next-hop destination), and recipient
ERROR:
```

***while Expected results should be:***

```
The Postfix error(8) delivery agent processes delivery requests from the queue manager. 
Each request specifies a queue file, a sender address, 
the reason for non-delivery (specified as the next-hop destination), and recipient
ERROR:
```

**Where I am wrong here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that in Bash double quotes don't cause `\n` to be interpreted as a newline character.

For this, I think I'd just include literal newlines in the string:

```
export info="The Postfix error(8) delivery agent processes delivery requests from the 
queue manager.
Each request specifies a queue file, a sender address,
the reason for non-delivery (specified as the next-hop destination), and recipient"
perl -i -plne 'print "$ENV{info}" if(/ERROR:/);' file
```

Otherwise, you could use `printf`, but that seems overkill:

```
export info=$(printf "The Postfix error(8) delivery agent processes delivery requests from the queue manager. \nEach request specifies a queue file, a sender address, \nthe reason for non-delivery (specified as the next-hop destination), and recipient")
perl -i -plne 'print "$ENV{info}" if(/ERROR:/);' file
```